# How do I change passwords that have been saved in the keyring?

Tags: password, gnome-keyring

I created a saved password via **System ▸ Preferences ▸ Passwords and Encryption Keys ▸ File ▸ New ▸ Stored Password**. How can I update it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expand "Login" by clicking the arrow beside it, right click on the password you wish to change and select "properties". Click the little arrow beside "Password" to show the password box, and click the "Show Password" option. You should now be able to see the old password, which you can overwrite with a new one.

My apologies, you can't edit it there ... although I'd swear I'd done it before. I can't edit my wireless password through the tool either. The upvotes on this answer should be reverted until I find the full answer.

Comment: Can you explain how to overwrite the old password? When I try typing in the text box, any key I press only causes the cursor to jump to the beginning of the password.

Comment: That's really odd, I was just going to post the same thing. Oddly, no one seems to have had this problem before. It's either purposefully designed this way (so that you either change the passwords in their appropriate places, or you have to delete and recreate it) -- in which case I don't understand the security concept. Or you've simply found a bug :)

Comment: Works as you first described in 11.04.