# How to discard saved password for samba share in unity?

Tags: unity, samba, password

I access samba shares from unity on Ubuntu 11.10 and saved username/pass for it. Now, I want to use a different username. Each time I go to the share and open it, it just opens without asking for credentials.

How can I force it to forget the saved credentials?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

With **Seahorse** it is possible to edit / remove passwords for network shares.

1. Enter `seahorse` in Dash.
2. Select *Passwords* tab, click on the *right arrow* after the folder icon to drop down the list of passwords.
3. Select your share and *right click -> Delete*.

At the next mount attempt, you will be required to supply a new password.

[image]

Comment: I was originally looking for how to sign out/log out of ftp sites that nautilus is logged into- this works for ftp equally well as samba.  I had to log out and log back into Ubuntu (16.04) after using seahorse for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 4):

Personal folder -> press Ctrl H to see hidden files -> enter .config/nautilus -> delete file servers

Comment: Seems a pretty drastic solution (see answer by lgarzo to selectively delete a sigle credetial using the GUI), but maybe in some particular situation it might help...

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that it is in the keyring, check here for more info:

[How do I change passwords that have been saved in the keyring?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/27636/how-do-i-change-passwords-that-have-been-saved-in-the-keyring)

Answer (score 0):

In recent Ubuntu (20.04.1 LTS) the arrangement of password is a bit different as given by @lgarzo screenshots.

[image: seahorse initail screen]

then double click default keyring

[image: user passwords saved in seahorse]

double click the one you want to delete
[image]

Then press delete button