# How to make nautilus forget SMB session passwords without logging out

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, password, samba, gvfs

I'm testing the accessibility of a couple of samba shares through `nautilus`. When inserting the password for the first time, I've chosen "*remember password until you logout*" but now I'd like to make `nautilus` forget about these passwords to continue testing. How can I do that without logging out?

I've already looked at `seahorse` as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236436/how-to-make-nautilus-forget-saved-password) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77127/how-to-discard-saved-password-for-samba-share-in-unity) to no avail. I think that `seahorse` gets involved only when storing passwords permanently.

P.s. I've also tried to kill `nautilus`, of course, as well as:

```
kill `pgrep gvfs`
```

Nothing worked.

Comment: Why can't you log out?

Comment: Because I was working on many different things and logging out/in is a plain waste of time if you know there is a faster way for making things happen. Obviously, if there is no such way, one is forced to log out/in. It's the same reason why you don't reboot to restart `samba` or `nfs`. There is a faster way of doing it and in this way you can test things faster.

Comment: @Avio did you ever find out how to do it?

Comment: No, sorry... :(

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
gnome-keyring-daemon -r
```

it worked for me.

source:
https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/108242/how-does-nautilus-store-passwords-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround that I am aware of is to select the **"Forget password immediately"** option while logging into the server. It showld be a radio button right beneath the username/password fill form.

That way when you unmount the device, you will be able to login again as the same ot different user.